# Intent .putExtra return null with PendingIntent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

This application allows me to start a service to remind me drinking. If i click the notification i want to see if the service is running or not, but i don't get any output with the Intent.putExtra method.

My MainActivity class:

```
Boolean isServiceRunning = false;
AlarmManager alarmManager;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;
TextView mainText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mainText = findViewById(R.id.mainTextView);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {
            mainText.setText("Service is paused");
    } else {
        mainText.setText("Service is running");
    }

}

public void sendNotification(View view) {

    if (!isServiceRunning) {
        isServiceRunning = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder service started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        mainText.setText("Service is running.");
        Intent i = new Intent(this, reciever.class);
        i.putExtra("isServiceRunning", isServiceRunning.booleanValue());

        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
    } else {
        isServiceRunning = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder service ended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mainText.setText("Service paused.");
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I think its possible to solve this problem with sharedpreferences, but this shouldn't be a good resolution.

EDIT:

My broadcast reciever class:

```
public class reciever BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, drinkReminder.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(drinkReminder.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(100, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_1_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("description")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_waterdrop)
            .setTimeoutAfter(30000)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

}
```

}

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. In any case, you are setting an alarm using `AlarmManager` and passing it a broadcast `Intent` to start `MainActivity`. This doesn't work. A broadcast `Intent` will only be seen by `BroadcastReceiver`s and when the alarm triggers it will not start any `Activity`. Also you talk about `Service`s, but there is no code here that deals with any `Service`. You also mention `Notification`s, but there is no code here to deal with those either. Please explain more about what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, i already got a broadcast reciever class, it is also working fine (stopping and resuming the programm), but if the broadcast reciever is sending to me a notification and if i click on it, it should check if the service is running or not. Thats the point.

I just added the broadcast reciever class.

Comment: You are adding the "extra" to the `Intent` that you pass to `AlarmManager`. This "extra" will be in the `Intent` that gets delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onReceive()`, but you don't do anything with it there.

Comment: When you click on the `Notification`, it will launch `drinkReminder`, which I hope is an `Activity`.

Comment: Thank you david, i just put a extra to the intent in the BroadcastReciever and it solved the problem!

Comment: Could you tell me please one more thing. Sometimes if i press the button to start the service, a notification appers after about 10 seconds, after this it shows all 10 minutes like it should. How can i fix this?

Comment: Glad to hear this solved your problem. I put my comments into an answer and also provided an answer to your followup question. You can accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer. This will help others who have a similar problem, get the question off the unanswered questions list and give you a few reputation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the "extra" to the `Intent` that you pass to `AlarmManager`. This "extra" will be in the Intent that gets delivered to your `BroadcastReceiver` in `onReceive()`, but you don't do anything with it there.

When you click on the `Notification`, it will launch `drinkReminder`, which I hope is an `Activity`.

---

You also said in a comment:

> Could you tell me please one more thing. Sometimes if i press the
>   button to start the service, a notification appers after about 10
>   seconds, after this it shows all 10 minutes like it should. How can i
>   fix this?

Here is your code for setting the alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

When you call `setRepeating()`, the 2nd parameter specifies the first time the alarm should go off, and the 3rd parameter specifies the repeat interval. You've told alarm manager that you want the first alarm to trigger immediately and then every 10 minutes after that.

If you want the first alarm to trigger 10 minutes after you press the button, you need to adjust the second parameter so it represents a time that is 10 minutes in the future, like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis() + (1000 * 60 * 10), 1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: This happens if you copy pase the code and don't think about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the code in onCreate() and putExtra() ,you can create two pending intents in each case and each intent uses a different broadcast receiver. In that broadcast receiver you can print the separate toast messages.

MyBroadcastRecieverStart.java

```
 public class MyBroadcastReceiverStart extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder service started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

MyBroadcastReceiverStop.java

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiverStop extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Toast.makeText(this, "Reminder service ended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```

SendNotification method -

```
public void sendNotification(View view) {

if (!isServiceRunning) {
    isServiceRunning = true;

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    mainText.setText("Service is running.");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiverStart.class);


    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
} else {
    isServiceRunning = false;

    mainText.setText("Service paused.");
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiverStop.class);


    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pendingIntent);
    alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
}
}
```

If you write alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent) in else block , it is cancelling an intent which does not exist as you have created the intent in if block and it does not get created if else gets executed , so I have created the intent in else block also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but starting and pausing the service worked fine, because i declared the PendingIntent before the onCreate() method. I also got a broadcast reciever before, i just edited my question.